Next Js Google Auth
I am new to frontend development and currently trying to implement Google login in my login. I want my frontend to send google token to my backend when i click on login with google.
When this Button is clicked, I don't know how but in my frontend i want to send the google token to my backend to validate.
  <a className={styles.continue_with_email} href="">
        Continue With Email
      </a>

Is this possible?
I am sorry if you did not get my question.


install google oauth package

npm install @react-oauth/google@latest

Get your Google API client ID (here)

Configure your OAuth Consent Screen (here)

Wrap your application with GoogleOAuthProvider and create the button.


import { GoogleOAuthProvider, GoogleLogin } from "@react-oauth/google";

export default function LoginByGoogleComponent() {
  const handleLogin = (credentialResponse) => {
    // this contains the response from google you can get the token from here
    console.log(credentialResponse);
  };

  const handleLoginError = (err) => {
    console.log("Login Failed");
  };

  return (
    <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId="<your_client_id>">
      <GoogleLogin onSuccess={handleLogin} onError={handleLoginError} />
    </GoogleOAuthProvider>
  );
}

or if you want to use a custom button
import { useGoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google';

const login = useGoogleLogin({
  onSuccess: tokenResponse => console.log(tokenResponse),
});

<button onClick={() => login()}>Sign in with Google </button>;

checkout the google oauth button package readme for more info here
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google
